# Disable user's ability to change FileVault recovery key

Tags: macos, filevault

How can we disable user's ability to change FileVault recovery key using `fdesetup changerecoverykey` ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the user from the admin group would be the simplest method. The `fdesetup` needs `sudo` permissions or someone to re-enable the root user. Both of those options are possible when you have admin credentials.